# Robo script aborts when using SwipeRefreshLayout

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-test-lab

My Robo script aborts when it encounters a layout in this structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".ui.AuftraegeActivity">

<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/projekte_listview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:divider="#d3d3d3"
            android:dividerHeight="2dp"
            android:paddingStart="10dp"
            android:paddingEnd="10dp"
            android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
            android:visibility="gone"
            tools:visibility="visible" />
</androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

<include layout="@layout/navdrawer" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Here i try to click on the first entry of the `ListView`.

The visibility of the `ListView` is set to visible inside the `AuftraegeActivity` after a successful sync with the server. While syncing a (UI-Blocking) Progressbar is displayed.

Removing the `SwipeRefreshLayout` let the Robo script run successfully.

Here is the relevant part of the Robo script:

```
{
"eventType": "LIST_ITEM_CLICKED",
"timestamp": 1542633892083,
"replacementText": "",
"actionCode": -1,
"delayTime": 0,
"canScrollTo": false,
"elementDescriptors": [
  {
    "className": "android.widget.LinearLayout",
    "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
    "adapterViewChildPosition": 0,
    "groupViewChildPosition": -1,
    "resourceId": "de.tarent.ngop.android.debug:id/ll_auftrag_list_item_container",
    "contentDescription": "",
    "text": ""
  },
  {
    "className": "android.widget.ListView",
    "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
    "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
    "groupViewChildPosition": 0,
    "resourceId": "de.tarent.ngop.android.debug:id/projekte_listview",
    "contentDescription": "",
    "text": ""
  },
  {
    "className": "androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout",
    "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
    "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
    "groupViewChildPosition": 0,
    "resourceId": "de.tarent.ngop.android.debug:id/swipeRefreshLayout",
    "contentDescription": "",
    "text": ""
  }
]
},
```

Answer (score 0):

As a way to troubleshoot this problem, it would help if you recorded the same actions using Espresso Test Recorder (in Android Studio, Run -> Record Espresso Test) and see if the test has the same issue. If yes (most probably), it will give us a detailed error message about what went wrong.

As a workaround for now, you can remove the last element descriptor for your LIST_ITEM_CLICKED action, i.e., remove the last block in curly brackets (the one that mentions SwipeRefreshLayout) as well as the comma before it. Please let us know if that helped. Thanks!

Comment: The recorded Espresso test didn't even got to the activity (permission problems). I tried to fix them, but then other problems appeared. I also tried your workaroud, which did not helped. It failed again at the SwipeRefreshLayout.

Comment: What Android Studio version are you using? The most recent one should handle dynamic permission requests (if that was the problem you encountered). It would really help if you could reproduce this problem with an Espresso test, so if you encounter any issues along the way, please let me know.

As about Robo script workaround, do you mind replacing the whole block you posted above with the one in the following comment and checking if it works. Thank you!

Comment: Please see the Robo script block to replace the original one in the following answer.

Comment: I am using the newest one (v3.2.1). I cannot reproduce it with Espresso, it just fails at running. I tried with the new Robo script block, but it still fails at the same place.

Comment: Thank you for confirming. I am curious if the original problem happens due to dynamic update of the ListView visibility. Do you mind trying to make it permanently visible and checking if the original Robo script works?

Also, if you are comfortable with it, do you mind sharing your test matrix execution link for the original Robo script failure such that I can get more insight about it? Thanks!

Comment: Tried it, it didn't work. Sry, but i can't as it contains sensible information.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
"eventType": "LIST_ITEM_CLICKED",
"timestamp": 1542633892083,
"replacementText": "",
"actionCode": -1,
"delayTime": 0,
"canScrollTo": false,
"elementDescriptors": [
  {
    "className": "android.widget.LinearLayout",
    "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
    "adapterViewChildPosition": 0,
    "groupViewChildPosition": -1,
    "resourceId": "de.tarent.ngop.android.debug:id/ll_auftrag_list_item_container",
    "contentDescription": "",
    "text": ""
  }
]
},
```